# Whenever I open my anaconda command prompt the error message occurs, so help me with it

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have recently set up the latest version of anaconda and when I open my anaconda command prompt an error message occurs.
Due to this issue, I am also not able to set up venv in my anaconda.

I have tried to search that conda-645.tmp but I haven't found that in that particular location as well.

> Access is denied. The system cannot find the file C:\Users\UDIT. Could
>   Not Find C:\Users\UDIT DEO\AppData\Local\Temp\conda-645.tmp

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as administrator.
This should solve this error.

Comment: I had tried it running as administrator but the scene was not at all different and the same issue prevails.